# Proceeding conditionally to the next mergeMap? [ rxjs.Observable]

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'd like to convert the my nested Observables with the use of *pipe,map,mergeMap,* however there are conditions after which I want it to proceed

**observableFunction** is an Observable that loops through an array, once its finished you can move on to use the manipulated data

```
observableFunction(par1,par2)
.subscribe((resp) => {
  i++;
 //do stuff, manipulate resp   
  const lastIteration = someArray.length == i;

  if (lastIteration) {
   //do stuff
   observableFunction(par1a, par2a)
      .subscribe((resp) => {
        observableHandleFunction(resp)
          .subscribe((handledData) => {
            h++;
            const lastIterationSub = someNestedArray.length == h;

            //do stuff, manipulate handledData

            if (lastIterationSub) {
              console.log("done");

          });
      });
  }
});
```

How can I convert so that it does seem more easy to read by using the features of rxjs that are meant to be used in this scenario?
Like applying conditions to mergeMap?

```
observableFunction(par1,par2)
 .pipe(
    mergeMap((res1) => {
       //do stuff
       CONDITION={
         return observableFunction(par1a,par2a)
       }
    }),
    mergeMap((res2) => return observableHandleFunction(res2))
 )
 .subscribe((res3) => {
        h++;
        //do stuff
        const lastIterationSub = someNestedArray.length == h;

        if (lastIterationSub) {
          console.log("done");

        }
});
```

With a solution something like this its not gonna work with the condition, leading to an error

Comment: As i can see from your code, you are not using results of observableFunction at all in your code in your next operations?? You are just calling the function with par1, par2 then not using it on the next call of observableFunction since you are using par1a and par2a, right?

Comment: its a pseudo code of the original just to focus on the logic instead of the details
I do use the results from each observable, thats what the // do stuff comment is referring to

Answer (score 0):

First of all, nesting `subscribe` blocks is always a bad idea.

If your `observableFunction` emits single values (rather than a whole array at once) and when its done it emits a complete value, you can use `toArray` operator. So:

```
observableFunction(par1,par2)
.pipe(toArray())
// Here you will have an array of items, now you can proceed with something like:

observableFunction(par1,par2)
  .pipe(
    toArray(),
    mergeMap(array => {
    // If neccesary you can do the same here etc
    }))
```